# AJAX To show only a part of XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have this code to call the AJAX:

```
function loadXml(b,c)
{
var xmlhttp;
var x,xx,i;
var txt = "";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("POST");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div><br>";
              }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'> </span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<p class='pcontent'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</p>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<p> </p><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      }
    document.getElementById(c).innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",b,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If the funcion is `onLoad="loadXML('content.xml', 'divId')"`
And for example, this is my content.xml:

```
<BLOG>
    <POST>
        <TITLE><![CDATA[<a class="normal" href="">1st title</a>]]></TITLE>
        <CONTENT>
        1st
        </CONTENT>
    </POST>

    <POST>
        <TITLE><![CDATA[<a class="normal" href="">2nd title</a>]]></TITLE>
        <CONTENT>
        2nd
        </CONTENT>
    </POST>

    <POST>
        <TITLE><![CDATA[<a class="normal" href="">3rd title</a>]]></TITLE>
        <CONTENT>
        3rd
        </CONTENT>
    </POST>
</BLOG>
```

For example I have about 10 `<POST>` tags in my XML, so here is:
My **PROBLEM**: How can I only show the 2nd `<POST>` tag without showing the others?

I already tried wrapping the content of the `<POST>` with DIVs and tried this jQuery code but this didn't worked:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('div.bpost').filter(
    function(){
        return !$('div.bpost').eq(2);
    }).css('display','none');
});
```

**And it also seems that JavaScript *don't* work with the ajax content from XML. **

Comment: Not that it helps you to solve this issue, but _IE6 is dead_, IE 5 even more so. Even MS was glad to EOL it, it's no longer supported, so don't waste your time `try-catch`-ing to support it [It's dead and burried](http://www.nexhorizon.net/procorner/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/rip-ie6.jpg). Forget about it. `console.log` can help, BTW, as can parsing the XML, if it isn't parsed automatically

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, just in case the ancestors visit my site, so I added those. But I'll also block IE7 & below from visiting my site in the future. But for now,

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost3.shtml

```
var xmldata=mygetrequest.responseXML ;
   var rssentries=xmldata.getElementsByTagName("POST")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. its working.

```
function loadXMLDoc(b,c)
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("POST");

      txt=txt + "<tr>";
      xx=x[1].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[1].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";

    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You have never used arguments b & c in the function . if of no use delete it

Comment: I think that this didn't answered my question. My question was how can I only show the nth tag of the XML.

And also, did you just copied this from W3Schools? Because I think so.

Comment: I have editted it in w3sch0ols.com and your question was  " My PROBLEM: How can I only show the 2nd <POST> tag without showing the others?"